# How to find the point in convex set $C$ that is closest to $y\notin C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

How to find the point in convex set $C$ that is closest to $y\notin C$?

$C=\{ x\in \mathbb{R^2}:(x_1-1)^2+(x_2-1)^2\le1 \}$

and let $y\notin C $ but $y\notin \mathbb{R^2} $.

Comment: Your set $C$ is not convex as stated. Maybe *sum* of squares? Otherwise, minimize $(y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2$ subject to $x\in C$. Not linear programming though.

Answer (score 4):

$C$ is a disk, so the closest point is on the line connecting $(x_1,x_2)$ and $y$. It is $$\frac{y-(x_1,x_2)}{\|y-(x_1,x_2)\|}+(x_1,x_2) $$

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit?

Comment: You mean on the line connecting $y$ and the disc center $(1,1)$.

Comment: okay. $(x_1,x_2)$ is the center. thanks.

Comment: Why do we divide it by the norm?

Comment: @104078 We need to go the radius length from the center towards $y$. The radius is $1$, so the step should have length one as we get after normalization.